# calling javascript method on onclick and onkeypress events

Tags: javascript

I have a search box and search button. I want to call a javascript method in case somebody types in search box and hits enter or clicks on search button.

So far with keypress event it's working fine:

```
 function Search(e) {                                   
   if(e.keyCode==13) {                  
        //DO operation
   }
  }
```

If I want to call same function on onclick event of search button, how can I use same method  shown above. Only purpose here is not to duplicate same code by writing two different methods which at the end do same thing.

Comment: Extract "//Do operation" in a function and call this function from both key press handler and click handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add listeners to both events (`onclick` and `onkeypress`) and use event's `type`:

```
 function Search(e) {  
    if( e.type == 'click' || 
        (e.type=='keypress' && e.keyCode==13) ){
        //DO operation
    }       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W8x3d/) here.

```
function Search(e) {                                   
   var doOper = function() {
        //DO operation
   }
   if(e.keyCode==13) {                  
      doOper();
   }
   if(buttonClicked) {
      doOper();
   }
}
```